# RealmSwift in iOS issue with 'write' block

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

I am getting one more issue regarding write block - 'SharedRealm.realm.write()' - Error - "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled", how it can be handled.

This is the code:

```
func addItems(items:[Item]) {
    do {
        let rlm = try Realm()

        rlm.write { () -> Void in
            for item in items {
                rlm.add(item, update: true)
            }
        }
    }
    catch let rlmError {
        print("Realm() generated error: \(rlmError)")
    }
}
```

Still I am getting the same error - ":13: Call can throw but is not marked with 'try'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rlm.write { ... }` might throw an error as well as the initializer so you will need to add the `try` operator in front of this invocation, too.

Answer (score 1):

Since Realm() might throw an error you'll need to wrap it in a do { try } catch block

```
extension Realm {

    public class func saveClosure(dbClosure: (Realm)->()) {
        do {
            let rlm = try Realm()
            rlm.write { () -> Void in
                dbClosure(rlm)
            }

        }
        catch let rlmError{
            print("Realm() generated error: \(rlmError)")
        }
    }
}
```

Checkout https://gist.github.com/edwardIshaq/b5810ab35c30df10af24